# Embeding other module view in Elm lang

Tags: elm

How do I use this AnswerList somewhere so events are addressed properly? I'm struggling with this for too long already :/

```
module AnswersList (Model, Action, update, view, Answer) where

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class)

type alias Answer =
    { id : Int
    , answer : String
    , points : Int
    , visible : Bool
    }

type alias Model = List Answer

-- actions
type Action = ShowAnswer Int

update action model =
  case action of
    ShowAnswer aid ->
      let newAnswer a = if a.id == aid then { a | visible <- True } else a
      in
        List.map newAnswer model

-- view

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
      div [class "list-group"]
      (List.map (viewAnswer address) model)

viewAnswer : Signal.Address Action -> Answer -> Html
viewAnswer address answer =
  let answerText = if answer.visible then answer.answer else "........"
  in
    div [class "list-group-item", onClick address (ShowAnswer answer.id) ] [text answerText]
```

Now in other module view I want to simply add some AnswersList to view and I don't know how to achieve it :/ Could you help me?

I have some other module

```
model = { answers: AnswerList.model }
```

and I would like to pass events so to `AnswerList.update` somehow will handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok what I really needed was this example https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/master/examples/2/CounterPair.elm from https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial and yeah it totally makes sense :)